# Active_admin running an error when run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I'm trying to install ActiveAdmin under Rails 4 to generate my admin panel.

I added the gem and installed with the below commands:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
bundle install
rails g active_admin:install              # creates the AdminUser class
rails g active_admin:install User         # uses an existing class
```

But when I try to migrate I get an error:

```
$ rake db:migrate
==  AddDeviseToAdminUsers: migrating ==========================================
-- change_table(:admin_users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "admin_users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

As mentioned in [issue 753 on github](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/753) I changed the `AddDeviseToAdminUsers` migration from `change_table` to `create_table` but that results in this error:

```
==  AddDeviseToAdminUsers: migrating ==========================================
-- create_table(:admin_users)
rake aborted!
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Was there anything more to the second error? An SQL Exception? Your first error suggests that the table exists before the migrate is run.

Answer (score 1):

The exception you're seeing is due to a migration conflicting with your existing database structure. Your admin_users table already contains an "email" column, which is why you're seeing the error `duplicate column name: email`.

You should only run the `active_admin:install` generator **once**. Running the ActiveAdmin setup with a clean application should only involve the following:

```
# Add the BETA gem with Rails 4 support. The ActiveAdmin master
# branch is still in heavy development.
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'

# Bundle
bundle install

# Setup ActiveAdmin 
rails g active_admin:install
```

For more advanced cases, where you already have an ActiveRecord model for an admin user then you'd use this variant of the generator: `rails g active_admin:install MyAdminUser`

Comment: Hey @CMaresh, i deleted the compiled file, and started again, i added the gem, and ran bundle install, and then rails g active_admin:install MyAdminUser. I went to this error :usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:409:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'admin_root'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as

Comment: @zacchj You'll have to start from scratch on the application. My guess is your config/routes.rb now has ActiveAdmin.routes(self) listed twice. Also, I doubt you want your admin user's model to be "MyAdminUser".

Comment: I only have one ActiveAdmin.routes(self), at first it generated two, but i deleted one, but i always have the same error when i run rake db:migrate:           =  DeviseCreateAdminUsers: migrating =========================================
-- create_table(:admin_users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "admin_users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "admin_users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,

Comment: If you can, start with a clean database and ensure there is only one migration which is creating the table "admin_users".

Comment: Hey @CMaresh, thanks for your help, i feel stupid, i cleaned up my database, and tried to start again, i installed the gem, run bundle install, and i created the admin_users: "rails g active_admin:install", but now i have this error: usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:409:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'admin_root'  (ArgumentError). But i still don't find where admin_route already is :/